# Share a Wifi connection through cross ethernet cable on Mac OS X

Tags: networking, macos, ethernet

I need to test a device at work that requires wired Internet connection to operate. I can programme this device to fetch the latest source code from my host computer through network. But the way the network is set up at work forces me to use a wi-fi connection on my mac and a wired connection in the device. As a result, the devices are in completely different networks and although the connection works, there are some strange latency issues that make my job much too slow to perform (like.. a code update every 10 minutes).

We have no control over the network settings in my department.

I thought about getting a cross network cable, hooking the device directly into my machine, which would then operate as a proxy (maybe). But then how do I configure this machine (a macbook) to share it's wi-fi connection through the cable? The solution eludes me. Is it even possible?

I am assuming it can be done, because in the past I used a wi-fi hotspot feature from Mac OS X, but it was the complete opposite as my Internet connection was wired.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough in Sharing preference pane. Select Internet Sharing, then share network from WiFi to computers using ethernet. Your "hotspot" use in past would have been the opposite - sharing wired network to WiFi. macOS allows you to share FROM any incoming network interface TO any other valid connection.

Comment: And probably works with any type of cable? Or does it need to be crossed?

Comment: No crossover cable needed.

Comment: That's ridiculously simple. Yet it didn't work, as the network uses 802.1X and cannot be shared. I read that a VPN can be used, but I'm still looking for a simple way of doing that. Regardless, it's a separate problem, I reckon, so this answer will do. Cheers!